# clearInterval doesn't works and increases interval speed

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdowntimer, clearinterval

Im making a blackjack game which contains a timer. Timer should restart if player decides to draw a new card. When i press draw button it does reset but increments interval speed by 1.

```
const createCountDown = (isPlayerDrawed = false) => {
  delay = 10;
  let Timer = document.getElementById('timer');
  if (isPlayerDrawed == true) {
    delay = 10;
    clearInterval(timer);
    createCountDown(false);
  } else {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (delay <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        stay();
      } else {
        delay--;
        Timer.innerHTML = delay;
      }
    }, 1000)
    console.log(timer)
  }
}
```

[image]

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: the first clearInterval(timer) probably does nothing as the scope of the timer is restricted to the scope in where it is defined with "let timer". You should probably define the timer before the first "if", so it's in scope for both clearInterval calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, defining timer before first if did not change the situation.

Comment: providing a working code snippet would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const createCountDown = (isPlayerDrawed = false, delay) => {
counter = delay;
let Timer = document.getElementById('timer');
let interval = null
if (isPlayerDrawed === true) {
    clearInterval(interval);
} else {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        Timer.innerHTML = counter;

        if (counter <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            stay();
        } else {
            counter--;
        }

    }, 1000)
}
```

}

changing function like this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `let timer` is only scoped to the `else` block. Other references will refer to a global variable.

Here is how you can make it work:

```js
let Timer = document.getElementById('timer');
const stay = () => Timer.textContent = "timer expired!";

const createCountDown = (function () {
    let delay, timer;

    function reset() {
        delay = 10;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
        Timer.textContent = "";
    }
    
    reset();
    
    return function () {
        reset();
        Timer.textContent = delay;
        timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (delay <= 0) {
                reset();
                stay();
            } else {
                delay--;
                Timer.textContent = delay;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
})();
// Optionally start timer immediately:
createCountDown();

document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener("click", createCountDown);
```

```html
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
<p id="timer"></p>
```